# inputing a cell value/user input into a URL destination in Excel macro

Tags: excel, extract, vba

I have a Macro that extracts a table from a specific website.

How do I make the macro to receive data from the user or from a cell and input it into the URL destination?

```
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http://" _
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have url in any cell, eh. in cell A1 you have www.stackoverflow.com you go this way:

```
 With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http://" & Range("A1") & _
```

If you want to get this address from user you will go this way:

```
 With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
     "URL;http://" & InputBox("Write site address starting with www") & _
```

Possibly additional `&` which I added at the end could not be required but I cant' see further part of your code to decide.